# Passing a value from my Joomla module to a article

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am on Joomla 1.5 and I am trying to pass the username value of my login module, that shows as a greeting anytime a user is logged in, to a article so i'll be able to customize the article to the user's profile. What would be the best way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use Joomla's User Object.

Like :

```
$user = &JFactory::getUser();

echo $user->name;//You will get name,username,email etc .using same object
```

In the article section just use above line.
in components/com_content/view/article/default.php or any other view you want.

The user object will return the current logged user info.

hope this will help you..